# Fixed button positions relative to an imageview android

Tags: java, android, imageview, fixed

Basically I positioned a bunch of buttons relative to an imageview. When I launch the app, the buttons seem to be slightly off, but not by much. However, when I test it on diferent devices, the buttons seem to be displaced into different positions relative to the imageview. So my question is how can you fix button positions relative to an imageview across multiple android devices. I've been working on this problem for a while and I just can't seem to figure it out. If Anyone could post an example or provide some help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Xml would sound nice... But it sounds like something I saw earlier... Does it also happen when the Images are empty? I had the same thing when the text, or image, was larger than the ImageView... When you scroll down, then up, they reposition wrongly. Maybe not on all devices because some have higher DPI so the text/image fits

Comment: here is my xml http://pastebin.com/ygnBC6tB